# Excel IF-THEN function assistance

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a column "F" that has validated text (2 entries only "A" and "B") in it. I want to have another cell reference the validated data. What I want is a formula to do this

IF F5 = A then (O5-J5)*10, IF F5 =B then (J8-O8)*10

I feel like I have tried every combination and I keep getting a #NAME error or I get the formula reported not the answer.

I am happy for a longer approach like:

IF F5=A then =Z5 (I would have another 2 columns with the formula in it that I am trying to achieve.

I apologise if there is a similar question I haven't seen an example close to what I am trying to achieve

Comment: Please provide your sample file or screenshot about your problem table.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=IF(F5="A",(O5-J5)*10,IF(F5="B",(J8-O8)*10,""))
```

Comment: Thank you, that has done it but now it has presented a new problem I didn't think of being blank fields. I have attached spreadsheet

Comment: @KellyLaFontaine I don't see any link to your spreadsheet. Which cells are blank?

Comment: I jumped the gun when I said I have attached as I can't see a button to attach the file or a pic. But to answer the question my spreadsheet currently has 30 columns. But with each adjustment I am making I am creating new errors but a little thinking I am resolving my problem till I get to the one I cant.

Comment: So I have hit my new problem. I want a IFS function (I think) that says if B5 = XYZ the show a different page column and cell. What it is, is if Column B which has a code in it then reference the variables page that has the price of that code in it

Comment: Fixed that problem but keep making new ones. Think I need to figure out whole spreadsheet and formulas required then work backwards on the #Na's and #NAME errors I am getting now. If is all because of blank cells. But the one thing I really want to be able to do is add a new entry at the top of the sheet not the bottom. Say I have 500 records and today I need to add 10 more records I want them in lines 10 - 20 not 500 to 510 etc

Comment: @KellyLaFontaine You need to create/ask another question for the other problem(s) as inserting new rows was not asked with this question.

Answer (score 0):

nested IF() version:

=IF(F5="","",   IF(F5="A",(O5-J5)*10,   IF(F5="B",(J8-O8)*10,"")))

is same as IFS() version

=IFS(F5="","",   F5="A",(O5-J5)*10,   F5="B",(J8-O8)*10,    1=1,"")